# Having a photorealistic earth in the background of an animation

Tags: modeling, rendering, light

I have created a model of a satellite and created an animation for its tumbling, but it just occured to me that I'd need to have it be more realisitc mainly by having earth in the background at some parts.

I tried to add an earth model in the background with lighting and everything but it slows down everything drastically.

Is there a way to have an effect similar to that seen in the video?

[This video shows exactly what I have in mind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1vknXUUYulg)

Comment: Just add a simple background plane with an earth image texture, I am sure you can find plenty of those photos around the internet easily.

Comment: also I suggest you fix that typo in your title so your problem is more searcheable.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, both of you, I would use a simple background but I need this for a simulation so while I might not need it to be completely realistic I do have to at least capture some of the lighting and color effects, seeing how I am using this for an image-processing simulation and those are vital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, know that the [physical phenomenons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) that come in place in the Earth's atmosphere (including those that come at the edge between day and night) are rather complicated. So if you want to do realistic "GRAVITY-style" CGI, you have a lot of work, certainly much more than what you did with your satellite. 
If for some reason you don't want to simply use a single high-res photo of a low orbit view as the background and want to make it with as much CG as possible here's what you can start with :

- the Earth's texture has to be focused on a particular area, or else you will waste a ton of memory or simply have a pixelated result.
  I suggest using [OpenTopography](http://opentopo.sdsc.edu/raster?opentopoID=OTSRTM.042013.4326.1) to generate color and heightmap, because at this zoom level you should also see the displacement of the mountains.
- for the clouds layer I don't know of a better way than using an image like [this](https://www.google.fr/search?q=earth%20clouds%20only&safe=off&client=firefox-b&tbm=isch&tbs=rimg:CX-OYSJCJZv4IjiFFYHXTNoafQCbZI91vJ1U-UP8oBLVa9iixKnXmlSlncKjlsMA7uimvayGiUBDNt4ufjgeSCwHESoSCYUVgddM2hp9EWO1dTFspqiiKhIJAJtkj3W8nVQRc_1h0g1W0w-kqEgn5Q_1ygEtVr2BEtCZotqpP7ACoSCaLEqdeaVKWdEaRK6xvC7LEzKhIJwqOWwwDu6KYRx8kHhTWWRbgqEgm9rIaJQEM23hFMva-nJz5VASoSCS5-OB5ILAcREaMq2Lur7yNj&tbo=u&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLyPTU5IHVAhWPZVAKHciIBtMQ9C8IHA&biw=1360&bih=673&dpr=1#q=earth+clouds+map&safe=off&tbs=ic:gray,isz:lt,islt:10mp&tbm=isch), although it will not give very realistic results, since again at this zoom level you should see them in 3D and very sharp. You could even see the projection of their shadow in the atmosphere itself, which if you want to do that using volume scattering will explode your render time.
- for the day-night shift, you'd have to simulate the red twilight in some way. [image]
  Unfortunately I don't think there's any tutorial on that but if you know your nodes you can get something close.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response Chameleon, I tried to follow your recommendation and it sort of worked, I did get somewhere,
Here is where I got (http://imgur.com/1JdAxfq), I am not sure if this is allowed but I do want your input on one more thing, how would I get that "halo" effect at the edges, the image you have there clearly shows it.

Comment: it doesn't seem you've followed much of my advice (but it's also because I didn't go into the details on how to do it properly), so maybe you'll be better off with the Blender Guru tutorial https://youtu.be/9Q8PwcDzb8Y. It's not as good as what you would get with the techniques I proposed but it's rather light on memory and render time and he also explains the halo effect.